# MySQL Workbench trying to connect to localhost when connecting to remote server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MySQL Workbench gives me an error when trying to connect to a database it has connected to many times before.

"Cannot Connect to Database Server

Your connection attempt failed for user 'user' to the MySQL server at *something.aws.com*

Unable to connect to localhost"

I don't understand what localhost has to do with it??

I tried flushing DNS and pinging localhost successfully